# iText7 deferred signed pdf document shows “Error during signature verification.”

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature, itext7

I looked for solutions and other answers regardign the similar issues. Nothing is working for my case.

Scenerios: We have to develop an application using Java and iText 8.0.3, whose purpose is to sign pdf documents. The signing key is held by another company, let’s say it’s CompanyA.

These are the steps we are following:

1. Got the pdf document to sign ready.
2. Created a Temp pdf file which added an Empty Signature in the original pdf.
3. Read the Temp pdf to get the message digest. (Encode it to base64)
4. Send the message digest (Base64 encoded) to the CompanyA to get signed.
5. Get the signed digest (base64 encoded) from CompanyA.
   Do the base64 decoding. And embedded the result into the Temp pdf to get the final signed pdf.

Unfortunately its not working and i am getting it saying,

```
“Error during signature verification.  

ASN.1 parsing error:  

Error encountered while BER decoding:”
```

Below is relevant part of the code from our application which is being used for the above process:

```
    package com.etc;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.*;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.*;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Base64;

public class SignatureService {
    public static X509Certificate getCertificate(String base64String) throws Exception{
        byte[] encodedCert = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(base64String);
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream  =  new ByteArrayInputStream(encodedCert);

        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);

        return cert;
    }

    public static String getHashBase64Str2Sign() {
        try {
            // Add BC provider
            BouncyCastleProvider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
            Security.addProvider(providerBC);

            X509Certificate certificate = null;
            Certificate[] certs = null;

            try{
                certificate = getCertificate("certBase64");
                certs = new Certificate[]{certificate};
            } catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            byte[] sh = emptySignature("helloworld.pdf", "temp.pdf", "sig", certs);

            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sh);
        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static byte[] emptySignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname, Certificate[] chain)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), new StampingProperties());
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setPageRect(new Rectangle(100, 500, 200, 100));
        appearance.setPageNumber(1);
        appearance.setCertificate(chain[0]);
        appearance.setReason("For test");
        appearance.setLocation("HKSAR");
        signer.setFieldName(fieldname);

        PreSignatureContainer external = new PreSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
        signer.signExternalContainer(external, 8192);

        return external.getHash();
    }

    private static void createSignature(String src, String dest, String fieldName, byte[] sig)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest)) {
            PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, os, new StampingProperties());

            IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(sig);

            PdfSigner.signDeferred(signer.getDocument(), fieldName, os, external);
        }
    }

    public static class PreSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {
        private final PdfDictionary sigDic;
        private byte[] hash;

        public PreSignatureContainer(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter) {
            sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
            sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
            sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
            String hashAlgorithm = "SHA256";
            BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

            try {
                this.hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new GeneralSecurityException("PreSignatureContainer signing exception", e);
            }

            return new byte[0];
        }

        @Override
        public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
            signDic.putAll(sigDic);
        }

        public byte[] getHash() {
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public static void embedSignedHashToPdf(String signedHash) {
        try {
            byte[] sig = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signedHash);
            // Get byte[] hash
            //SignatureService app = new SignatureService();
            createSignature("temp.pdf", "output.pdf", "sig", sig);
        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class MyExternalSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {

        protected byte[] sig;

        public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] sig) {
            this.sig = sig;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] sign(InputStream arg0) throws GeneralSecurityException {
            return sig;
        }

        @Override
        public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary pdfDictionary) {

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       // System.out.println("Hash:" + getHashBase64Str2Sign());
        String hash = getHashBase64Str2Sign();

        System.out.println(hash);

        // Send the hash and get signed hash from CompanyA

        String signatureString = //.....

        embedSignedHashToPdf(escapeCharFromSignature(signatureString));
    }

    public static String escapeCharFromSignature(String str) {
        return str.replace("\r\n", "");
    }
}
```

Below are the source and temp/output pdf after signing:

[helloworld.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sR-RXYb9-E-brdlJmArav5YCKSLYed8b/view?usp=share_link)

[temp.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ej2vQGhwX2N5OpFgoUGl6IqgId_Ovs_N/view?usp=share_link)

[output.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12uggZ_sVBjQsQ-X6MU3iHQAMNT-snsfa/view?usp=share_link)

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE**

So I have updated the pre signature container, now I am getting all thing valid, except the message "Document has been altered or corrupted"

```
public static class PreSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {
    private final PdfDictionary sigDic;
    private byte[] hash;

    public PreSignatureContainer(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter) {
        sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
        sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
        sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        String hashAlgorithm = "SHA256";
        BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        X509Certificate certificate = null;
        Certificate[] certs = null;

        try{
            certificate = ("cert");
            certs = new Certificate[]{certificate};
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            this.hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
            PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = new PdfPKCS7(null,certs , "SHA-256", null, digest, false);
            byte[] sh = pkcs7.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash,PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null);
            this.hash = sh;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new GeneralSecurityException("PreSignatureContainer signing exception", e);
        }

        return new byte[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
        signDic.putAll(sigDic);
    }

    public byte[] getHash() {
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Here's the updated PDF:
[helloworld.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sR-RXYb9-E-brdlJmArav5YCKSLYed8b/view?usp=share_link)

[temp.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ej2vQGhwX2N5OpFgoUGl6IqgId_Ovs_N/view?usp=share_link)

[output.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12uggZ_sVBjQsQ-X6MU3iHQAMNT-snsfa/view?usp=share_link)

**UPDATE 2**

Here's the PreSignatureContainer uses:

```
 private static byte[] emptySignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname, Certificate[] chain)
        throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), new StampingProperties());

    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setPageRect(new Rectangle(100, 500, 200, 100));
    appearance.setPageNumber(1);
    appearance.setCertificate(chain[0]);
    appearance.setReason("For test");
    appearance.setLocation("HKSAR");
    signer.setFieldName(fieldname);

    PreSignatureContainer external = new PreSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
    signer.signExternalContainer(external, 8192);

    return external.getHash();
}

public static class PreSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {
    private final PdfDictionary sigDic;
    private byte[] hash;

    public PreSignatureContainer(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter) {
        sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
        sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
        sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        String hashAlgorithm = "SHA256";
        BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        X509Certificate certificate = null;
        Certificate[] certs = null;

        try{
            certificate = getCertificate("cert");
            certs = new Certificate[]{certificate};
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
            PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = new PdfPKCS7(null,certs , "SHA-256", null, digest, false);
            byte[] sh = pkcs7.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash,PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null);
            this.hash = sh;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new GeneralSecurityException("PreSignatureContainer signing exception", e);
        }

        return new byte[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
        signDic.putAll(sigDic);
    }

    public byte[] getHash() {
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot yet analyze your PDFs as I'm only on a smart phone. I assume, though, that the issue is that the "signed hash" you get from company A indeed is only a naked signed hash, not a full blown signature container which is required for your `MyExternalSignatureContainer`.

Comment: What might be my step after I received it, in such case?

Comment: Ok, I now had the time to take a closer look at the files you provided. Indeed, you appear to get a naked 4096bit signed hash, not a signature container. *"What might be my step after I received it, in such case?"* - Well, actually you even have to do something additional *before*: When creating a signature container, you usually don't sign the document hash directly. Instead, you build a set of "signed Attributes" (among which there is the document hash), calculate the hash of these attributes, and sign that. With those attributes and their signed hash you then build a signature container.

Comment: Depending on your other requirements, you can implement that in different ways. ***(A)*** If you do not really need the deferred signing architecture, you can simply switch to use `PdfSigner.signDetached` instead of `PdfSigner.signExternalContainer` using an `IExternalSignature` implementation that calls company A; here you delegate that signature container construction to iText. ***(B)*** Otherwise, you can prepare and afterwards construct the signature container using iText's  `PdfPKCS7` class or a function of your signature provider of choice. ...

Comment: ***(C)*** If PAdES signatures are ok for you, you alternatively can use iText's `PadesTwoPhaseSigningHelper`.

Comment: Any code reference for case A or B?

Comment: I have updated the pre signature container, Now I get document has been altered or corrupted message. Updated code is in the original post.

Comment: In your updated example files the signed hash is the document hash, not anything related to the signed attributes. Considering your updated `PreSignatureContainer`, though, that is surprising, as you eventually set `this.hash` to the attributes. (By the way, depending on what exactly your company A does, you'll need to hash attributes first.) So, are you sure you actually use the new `PreSignatureContainer`?

Comment: @KJ *"it has a very unusual header 2nd line (binary marker) that is removed downstream"* - it is removed (well, _replaced_) indeed, but it is removed before hashing, so this isn't an issue.

Comment: *"that trailer modified ID looks odd"* - Indeed, that's odd. Valid but odd.

Comment: @mkl I have updated again which shows the PresignatureContainer uses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257134/discussion-between-aaa111-and-mkl).